# Prayer for Trideva along with Tridevi?

Tags: mantras, prayer, trinity

Prayer for Trideva along with Tridevi:

```
गुरुर्ब्रह्मा गुरुर्विष्णुः
गुरुर्देवो महेश्वरः ।
गुरुःसाक्षात् परब्रह्म
तस्मै श्रीगुरवे नम: ॥
```

This Prayer, Mantra has Trideva only, any verse which has both Trideva along with Tridevi?

I want to Pray Trideva and Tridevi.

Comment: That prayer is not for Trimurti. It's a prayer to Guru.

Comment: According to one tradition, Sri Dattatreya represents Trimurti and his consort Sri Anagha Lakshmi represent Tridevi

Comment: Alone "Om" contains everything inside itself.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The prayer contains, Trideva(3) names.. So I was looking for prayer which include all 6 names (Trideva(3) and Tridevi(3))

Comment: "any verse which has both Trideva along with Tridevi?" NO, do you ever heard about Female Guru's in Vedas?

Comment: It doesnt have to be female Guru.. I just want to pray trimurti and their consorts.

Comment: During puja it is common for Pandits to chant - लक्ष्मीनारायणाभ्यां नमः। उमामहेश्वराभ्यां नमः। वाणीहिरण्यगर्भाभ्यां नमः। etc. Try this